# How do I stop a linux kernel from being removed automatically

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mouse, freeze

I just purchased a new HP Aero 13 for my significant other's B-day.  I installed the latest version of 20.04.4 LTS which has the 5.13.0.30 Kernel and it works great.  Immediately after install, software updater popped up to install a bunch (550MB) packages including Kernel 5.15.0-41 and rebooted.

This 5.15 kernel is faulty in many different ways.  It freezes the computer nearly immediately.  e.g It boots, I get to pwd screen enter the pwd, and nothing, frozen.  Sometimes it freezes before entering the pwd. There are times when I get past the pwd screen and it showed the desktop so, I begin to add Chrome browser or other apps and then it freezes.  The point is 5.15 is completely messing up this computer.  I am able to use the alt+prt sc+REISUB to make it reboot or otherwise hard shut down.  At one point the entire screen turned upside down with the mouse working, the mouse acted inversely as well, it was like using a mirror to run the computer.  This HP is not a tablet nor has the ability to rotate the screen.  Trying to get information to diagnose could be very time consuming if not impossible while operating 5.15.0-41.

Without a the mouse working I was able to open a terminal and change grub to point to 5.13.0-30 and saved it.  That took about an hour as the default terminal opens text files and highlights each line by default which made editing very hard to see and I made some mistakes initially. I did get it proper after some time. I was able to use key controls to save the file, switched back to terminal, ctl+c to stop the gedit program then, ran update-grub and rebooted into 5.13.0-30.

I used `Default="Advance options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-30-generic"`

I think that was the best way.  Using something like `Default=1>3` would not keep the kernel order proper during the next kernel update.

Now I need to do something to keep this kernel until a newer kernel finally operates this machine properly.  In the meantime it will default into 5.13.

**How do I keep old kernels from being removed?**

I really need to keep this kernel for now.  I remember there was a time when old kernels were not removed automatically so I'm hoping it is still possible.  Space is not a problem with a 1T ssd.

Thank you for any assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Synaptic Package Manager, search for the kernel packages, select them, then from the Package menu untick the "Automatically Installed" option.

That will set them to "manually installed" so they won't be automatically removed.

[image]

Comment: This worked like charm, so far no 5.13 removal.  Thanks for the information.